# add images in bootstrap grid of rows and columns dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="emojimodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="emojilabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" id="bgcolorheader">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select emoji</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- to be dynamically populated from js -->
                <div class="modal-body" id="modalDiv"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to add images in rows and columns of a bootstrap grid in a modal. I need to do that dynamically using jquery. I started that with rows first and then I need to extend the same logic for each column as well. The following function displays the first image only. How can I have the image displayed in multiple rows?

```js
function createGrid(rownum, imagearraySrc) {
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rownum; rowIndex++) {
        var rowid = "row" + rowIndex;
        var $row = $("<div>", {
            "class": "row",
            "id": rowid
        });
        $('#modalDiv').append($row);

        var imgid = "img" + rowIndex;
        var $img = $("<img>", {
            "id": imgid,
            "src": imagearraySrc[rowIndex],
        });
        $($row[rowIndex]).append($img);
    }
};
```

The rownum value getting passed to the function is 2. imagearraySrc contains src of all the images. The goal is to have x rows and y columns and have images in each of them. All of this will get displayed in a modal and a user will chose one of them. The attached code is a starting point and is not helping me move forward. Can someone help with it?

Comment: Please share your `HTML` codes as well

Comment: Shared the html as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/kzxh0r5u/

```js
var imagearraySrc = ["http://via.placeholder.com/350x150", "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150", "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"];

function createGrid(rownum, colnum) {
  var imgCnt = 0;
  $('#modalDiv').append('<div class="container-fluid"></div>')
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rownum; rowIndex++) {
    $('#modalDiv > div.container-fluid').append('<div class="row" id="row' + rowIndex + '"></div>');
    for(var colIndex = 0; colIndex < colnum; colIndex++) {
      $('#row' + rowIndex).append('<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"><img src="' + imagearraySrc[imgCnt] + '" class="img-responsive" /></div>');
      imgCnt++;
    }
  }
};

createGrid(2,3);

$('#emojimodal').modal('show');
```

```css
.row{
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="emojimodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="emojilabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" id="bgcolorheader">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select emoji</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- to be dynamically populated from js -->
        <div class="modal-body" id="modalDiv"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

First we need to add `.container-fluid` to **modal body**, then add `rows` along with `column`